# "Interesting" subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with exactly three limit points

Tags: general-topology

Baby Rudin Exercise 2.5: Find a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with exactly three limit points.

The easy answer is the union of three subsets which each have one limit point, i.e. $\{\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n} + 1, \frac{1}{n} + 2\}(n=1, 2, 3, \dots)$ which have limit points $0, 1, 2$.

My question is that is there a more "interesting" example? As in, not just a set that is the union of three sets which each have exactly one limit point? Of course "interesting" can be quite subjective, but I trust you get generally what I mean.

Comment: Well, you can always represent such a set as the union of three sets each with only one limit point...

Comment: $\{\sin((n+\frac1n)\frac\pi2):n=1,2,3,\ldots\}$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews What do you mean? Isn't that what I said in my "easy" answer?

Comment: I was saying that is the only sort of answer out there. @Soke Jason's answer gives the proof of this statement.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ohhh. I didn't realize "always" meant literally "always" and not like "oh, you could *always* do this" as in "if you are being lazy, you could do it this way." Darn english language.

Comment: I read it that way at first, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $D\subset\mathbb{R}$ has three limit points $a<b<c$, then let $D_1=\{x\in D\,:\,x\le\frac{a+b}2\}$, $D_2=\{x\in D\setminus D_1\,:\,x\le\frac{b+c}2\}$ and $D_3=D\setminus(D_1\cup D_2)$. Then $D$ is the disjoint union of $D_1,D_2$ and $D_3$ and each has one limit point ($a,b$ and $c$ respectively). So I guess your question boils down to "Are there interesting subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ with exactly one limit point?" to which my answer would probably be "Not really".

Comment: @ Jason: Very elegant solution! How about throwing in a set without limit point, for a set with single limit point. For example, the set $\mathbf{Z}\cup \{\frac1n\mid n\in\mathbf{Z}^+\}$